# Input validation using TableCellEditor in jTables

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, validation

I have a JTable with 3 columns. One on the columns must have an integer value and I must validate the input before the cell loses its focus.

I've used cell editor and overrided the stopCellEditing() function. I've wrote the validation in stopCellEditing and it does keep the focus on the cell but but my problem is this:

- the column cannot accept more than one value (if I move to editing another cell the content disappears!!)
- I cannot hit enter if I'm editing one of the cells in this column!

this is my editor class:

```
public class MyEditor extends DefaultCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    public MyEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        Object obj = delegate.getCellEditorValue();
        if (obj is not an integer) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and this is how I'm using in in my Frame:

> studentsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new
>   MyEditor());

Plz help me :)

Comment: And what is the desired behavior when invalid input is entered, and the user changes the focus ? Revert to an old value, use a default value, ...

Comment: the condition will never be true - the value returned from a textField is _always_ just a String, so you detoriated the default handling, as @camickr already noted. He's spot on in the other bullets as well - it's plain wrong to not call super if the edit would be valid, that's where the listeners get notified -  so show an sscce for help :-).

Answer (score 2):

> One on the columns must have an integer value

No need to write a custom editor for this.

All you need to do is override the `getColumnClass()` method of JTable or your TableModel and the table will use the supplied Integer editor.

Regarding the code you posted:

1. It won't compile since your if condition is not valid. We want real code so we can spot possible logic errors. The code should also be posted in the form of an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).
2. There is no need to reference the delegate variable. Just invoke the getCellEditor() method directly.
3. Don't know if it makes a difference bu when I override stopCellEditing(), instead of returning true I use:

   `return super.stopCellEditing();`

Comment: it doesn't matter what's in the stopCellEditing(), cz even if I removed my code just returned true, I get the same result. Only when I remove the function everything comes normal again but of course no validation @camickr